# How to call plugin path in JS?

Tags: plugins, php, javascript, paths

I am using **wp-store-locator** plugin and I want to add plugin directory path to my JS.

```
html = "<li data-store-id='" + id + "'><div><p>" + storeImg + "<strong>" + store + "</strong><span class='wpsl-street'>" + address + "</span>" + address2 + city + " " + state + " " + zip + "</p>" + moreInfo + "<span><a href='plugin-urlpath/store-listings.php' class='more-details'>More details</a></span></div></li>";

return html;
```

How can I do that ? Plugin path is at the end of `html`.

**EDITED**:

This what I have done :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpsl-gmap', ( "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=" . $this->settings['api_language'] ), false, '', true ); 
wp_localize_script('wpsl-gmap', 'wpsl-gmap', array('pluginsUrl' => plugins_url(,__FILE__)));
```

Then Added this line to **wpsl-gmap.js**

```
var href = wpsl-gmap.pluginsUrl + '/path/to/resource';
html = "<li data-store-id='" + id + "'><div><p>" + storeImg + "<strong>" + store + "</strong><span class='wpsl-street'>" + address + "</span>" + address2 + city + " " + state + " " + zip + "</p>" + moreInfo + "<span><a href='" + href + "' class='more-details'>More details</a></span></div></li>";
```

It is giving no errors.But it is also not showing me the store location as well.

**NOTE** It was showing properly before doing this.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass any kind of data to your loaded scripts, in this case we need [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url):

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js');
wp_localize_script('my-script', 'myScript', array(
    'pluginsUrl' => plugins_url(),
));
```

Now you will have access to `myScript.pluginsUrl` in your script file:

```
var href = myScript.pluginsUrl + '/path/to/resource';
```

Comment: First, the second argument of `wp_localize_script` is the object name or variable name that will be accessible in JS and this name should contain only valid characters and the dash `-` is not, so try `wp_localize_script('wpsl-gmap', 'wpslGmap' ..` instead. Second, I dont know if this is a typo, but first argument must be provided in `plugins_url()` to pass the second argument, so fix your code to `plugins_url('', __FILE__)`.